# clrzmq Visual Basic 2012 subscriber socket not receiving messages

Tags: vb.net, publisher, subscriber

I'm having a few issues writing a basic tool to receive messages from a Publisher using zeroMQ in Visual Basic 2012, using clrzmq (acquired via NuGet). As you can see it's very basic - it should just pick up a message and print it to a Textbox.

```
Dim context As New ZMQ.Context
Dim subscriber = context.Socket(SocketType.SUB)
Dim emptyArray As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("")
subscriber.SetSockOpt(ZMQ.SocketOpt.SUBSCRIBE, emptyArray)
subscriber.Connect("tcp://eddn-gateway.elite-markets.net:9500")
Dim response = subscriber.Recv()
TextBox1.AppendText(response.ToString)
```

However, it refuses to receive any messages, even when I can see from a different tool that message are indeed being sent out by the Publisher. I know it connects ok because if not it throws an error. I was convinced I was not setting the SUBSCRIBE filter correctly hence the overkill to create an empty byte array.

I'm 100% stumped.